# High availability of Azure Service Bus and Function Apps

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-functions

I'm struggling at understanding if and what needs to be done to provide for high availability of two different types of Azure resources:

1. Azure Service Bus
2. Function Apps

Comment: you'll need to be more specific about this. You also seem to touch on 2 different subjects:

1. Azure Service Bus high availability and reliability
2. Function Apps high availability

I would advise that you rephrase your question and even break it down to 2 different one

Answer (score 0):

Service Bus guarantee at least 99.9% of the time for most of the service (includes Relay, Queues and Topics, Notification Hubs). Besides, replication and partitioning messaging entities (Each partitioned queue or topic consists of multiple fragments. Each fragment is stored in a different messaging store. If the corresponding messaging store is unavailable, Service Bus writes the message to a different fragment, if possible.) could be used as common solution for high availability.

The following article would be helpful, please read it.

- [High Availability and Disaster Recovery for Azure Service
  Bus](https://blog.nilayparikh.com/azure/messaging/cloud-architecture-patterns-high-availability-and-disaster-recovery-for-azure-service-bus/)

For Function Apps running on App Service Plans Microsoft guarantee that the associated Functions compute will be available 99.95% of the time. So if possible, you could run your Function App on an App Service Plan and enable the **Always On** setting.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that function apps are app such as web apps, mobile apps, logic apps and api apps and as such they are utilize the resources defined for a app service plan so as long as HA is defined for the hosting plan the hosted app will be in HA.

As for the service bus I don't understand if anything need to be done for HA or if it is natively highly available.